# How to get pyenv to work with Mac Automator on Mojave?

Tags: macos, shell, automator, pyenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm trying to create an Automator application on Mac OS X Mojave which starts my pyenv.

If I run this command from the bash shell it works fine:
`pyenv activate myenv`

However from within Automator I get the following error:

```
The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “[31;1m
Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.

[0m”

[31;1m
Failed to activate virtualenv.

Perhaps pyenv-virtualenv has not been loaded into your shell properly.
Please restart current shell and try again.

[0m
```

If I add `whoami` at the start of the shell script, then it shows that Automator is running the script as me, so it should have the same `$PATH` etc. However if I echo the `$PATH` variable it is clearly not the same as when I run it directly from the shell. Manually setting the `$PATH` in the script doesn't help either.

Oddly, running `python --version` in the script does not generate any output.
Running `which python` does generate output: `/usr/bin/python`

Any clues as to why this doesn't work?

Comment: You probably need to `source ~/.bashrc` before executing `pyenv commands`.

Comment: Thx. Tried `~/.bash_profile` for my case but no change to output.

Comment: What does running `env` output?

Comment: I have this same problem, but I use `zsh` instead and have `source ~/.zshrc` as the first thing in my script. Still no luck. I can't imagine the difference between my normal `zsh` from homebrew (5.9) and the one installed with macOS 12 (5.8.1) is the cause of the difference, I reckon it might be the fact that there's no tty but I'm not sure.

Comment: Based on [this open issue](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/389), it seems like `pyenv activate` might not be meant to work with non-interactive shells, which would mean that neither would `pyenv-virtualenv`. The developers have not answered the question yet, though, so it remains to be seen whether this can work at all or not.